# Avoid permanent redirect to login page http://127.0.0.1:3000/login

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I have a problem using nuxt/auth v4.9.1.
when I logged in and I enter a URL for example http://127.0.0.1:3000/configuration/locations it redirects me to the login page http://127.0.0.1:3000/login while I I'm already logged in and my token hasn't expired yet.

Please how to avoid this redirect?

Nuxt.config.js

```
router: {
        middleware: ['auth']
      },
      // Auth Strategies
      auth: {
        redirect: {
            login: '/login',
            logout: false,
            callback: false,
            home: '/'
        },
        token: {
            property: 'accessToken',
            global: true,
            maxAge: 1800
        },
        refreshToken: {
            property: 'refreshToken',
            data: 'refreshToken',
            maxAge: 60 * 30
          },
        strategies: {
            local: {
                endpoints: {
                    login: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, url:'oauth/v2/token', method: 'post', propertyName: "accessToken" },
                    refresh: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, url: '/oauth/v2/token/refresh', method: 'post', propertyName: 'refreshToken'},
                    user: { url: 'security/users/me', method: 'get', propertyName: false}
                },
                /* user: {
                    property: 'data'
                }, */
                tokenType: 'Bearer'
            }
        }
      }
```

Someone to help me please?

Comment: You control what happens on your page based on whether or not the auth token is present and valid.

Comment: yes, if the authentication token or so has expired it redirects to the login page in fact.

Comment: are you sure that you are logged in and the cookie is there ? might also be helpful if you included your locations page

Comment: I am logged in when I put this.$cookies.set('userme', this.result) it gives me undefined. cookie-universal-nuxt package